# Reading output file of SQLCMD using Java

Tags: java, sql-server, logging, process, sqlcmd

I am executing a bunch of SQL scripts and trying to read the output log file, looking for errors, after each file is executed.

Here's how I execute the script.

```
String strCommand = "sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME -d DBNAME -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -r0 -i \"SCRIPT.sql\" 2> \"OUTPUT.LOG\" 1> NULL";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strCommand);
process.waitFor();
```

I've redirected the standard output to `NULL` and errors to the log file. Immediately following the execution of the above statements, I try to read the contents of the OUTPUT.LOG file, using `File Reader` and `BufferedReader`. An exception is thrown when trying to open the OUTPUT.LOG file.

> (The system cannot find the file specified)

I check the path where the file should be saved, and needless to say, it isn't there. When I try to manually execute the command via Command Prompt, it works and writes the log file with errors, as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your redirections (the 2> etc) will work if you are running from a command shell, but not if you run directly from java like this.

Try the following (for Windows):

```
String strCommand = "cmd /c sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME -d DBNAME -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -r0 -i \"SCRIPT.sql\" 2> \"OUTPUT.LOG\" 1> NULL";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strCommand);
process.waitFor();
```

Note the addition of `cmd /c`, which will run the string in a command shell.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I believe using `cmd` executes the command in the shell and then exits, which finishes writing the file.